# Query String Parameter Fails to Populate .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am upgrading an app from MVC to .NET Core. The ruleSetId parameter works in MVC, but not in .NET CORE. Why is ruleSetId = when I sent 203389?

POST https://localhost:44313/Customer/RuleSet/CreateRule?ruleSetId=203389

[image]

Comment: Add `[FromQuery]` attribute to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[FromQuery]` attribute for `ruleSetId` and for other parameter you want get it from body use `[FromBody]`

See this link about [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)